# Method name not valid webservice

Tags: c#, angularjs, web-services

I am creating a web app in which I am using the following web service

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public void insertarea(string comname, string brandname, string zone, string location, string area)
{
   string id = "";
   var json = "";
   SqlCommand cmdcom = new SqlCommand("select id from companydetails where comname='" + comname + "'", con);
   con.Open();
   SqlDataReader drcom = cmdcom.ExecuteReader();
   while (drcom.Read())
   {
       id = drcom["id"].ToString();
   }
   con.Close();
   List<object> addarea = new List<object>();
   if (brandname != "select")
   {
       cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into companyallot values('" + id + "','" + location + "','" + area + "','" + zone + "','" + brandname + "',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)", con);
       con.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       json = js.Serialize("Area Added with brandname");
       con.Close();
   }
   else
   {
       cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into companyallot values('" + id + "','" + location + "','" + area + "','" + zone + "',Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null)", con);
       con.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       json = js.Serialize("Area Added For All Brands");
       con.Close();
   }
   Context.Response.Write("{" + '"' + "info" + '"' + ":" + json + "}");
}
```

But I am continuously getting an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: insertarea Web Service method name is not valid.
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)

I tried and changed the method name a few times but still face the same error.
Does anyone know what is wrong here?

And this is my `angularjs` function

```
$scope.updatefunction = function (param) {
   $scope.updateparam = param;
   console.log($scope.updateparam.comarea);

   $http.get('/allotcompany.asmx/areaintable', {
      params: {
         comname: $scope.mdcomname,
         brandname: $scope.mdbrandname,
         zone: $scope.mdzone,
         location: $scope.location,
         area: $scope.updateparam.comarea
      }
   }).then(function (response) {
      alert(response.data.info);
      $scope.gettableinfo();
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look at your  Angularjs code I see that you call the 'areaintable' method name `$http.get('/allotcompany.asmx/areaintable'`.

What happens when you change it into  `$http.get('/allotcompany.asmx/insertarea'`